# Remember Me Button Click and set it to default

Tags: button, click, sharedpreferences

How To Remember Button Click Between Two Buttons Using Check Box (Remember Me) And Skip That Activity Next Time If Remember Me Is Checked.

1) Splash
2) Have 2 Buttons And 1 CheckBox ( Remember Me)
3) If Button 1 Is Clicked Start One Activity
4) If Button 2 Is Clicked Start Another Activity

[Screen Shot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OazVQ.jpg)

Comment: This question is too vague.  We need more details as to what you've tried and why it isn't working

Comment: There are two activities (3 & 4) Contain different languages.

so user have to select language by pressing button on activity 2.

if user want to set its default language in by using check box he can set it as a default.

but when he set any default 
then next time start that activity directly after splash screen.

i am a beginner.

so please give me a full code for this or any other solution.

Thank You.

Comment: i have added sample screen shot also.